# Nsubstitute check if setter has been called

Tags: c#, properties, setter, nsubstitute

I have an interface with a property:

```cs
public interface Filterable<T>
{
    Filter<T> Filter { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method simelar to this one:

```cs
public void SetTheFilter<T>(Filterable<T> filterable, Filter<T> filter)
{
    If (filter.IsActive)
        filterable.Filter = filter;
}
```

How can I ensure with NSubstitute with in a unit test that the filter has been set. I tried to do it in the following way, but it just tests the getter:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void SetTheFilter_WhenCalledWithFilterActive_SetsTheFilterOfFilterable()
{
    var filterable = Substitute.For<Filterable<String>>();
    var filter = new StringFilter();

    SetTheFilter(filterable, filter);

    var tmp = filterable.Recieved().Filter;
}
```

Does anybody knows how to test, if the setter has been called?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way to test this is to just read the value back out of the property:

```
Assert.AreEqual(filterable.Filter, filter);
```

If for some reason you really want to test a setter was called, you can do:

```
filterable.Received().Filter = filter;
```

Comment: With the second option you can check that the property get set the expected number of times. e.g. filterable.Received(1).Filter = filter;

Comment: See details in the documentation here: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/